# Having trouble with making K Nearest Neighbors work in R Studio

Tags: r, knn

I'm trying to use the knn function in r but I keep getting this error message when I try to compute it.

```
> knn(Taxi_train,Taxi_test,cl,k=100)
Error in knn(Taxi_train, Taxi_test, cl, k = 100) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In knn(Taxi_train, Taxi_test, cl, k = 100) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In knn(Taxi_train, Taxi_test, cl, k = 100) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I don't know what exactly is wrong with my code so I need some help to get it working.

I tried making sure that all the variables are numeric but that didn't change anything. It may also be an issue with my cl factor in the knn equation.

Here is what my code is currently:

```
    
date<-chicago_taxi$date
class(date)
Date <- as.Date(date)
class(Date)

Julian <- yday(Date)
class(Julian)
head(Julian)
chicago_taxi <- cbind(chicago_taxi,Julian)

chicago_taxi$seconds <- as.numeric(chicago_taxi$seconds)

set.seed(7777)
train_set <- sample(1:13081,10400,replace = FALSE)
Taxi_train <- chicago_taxi[train_set,]
Taxi_test <- chicago_taxi[-train_set,]

cl <- Taxi_train$payment_type

scale(chicago_taxi$miles)
scale(chicago_taxi$seconds)
scale(chicago_taxi$Julian)

knn(Taxi_train,Taxi_test,cl,k=100)
```

Comment: iF I recall correctly, knn uses the Euclidean distance.There is no way to compute euclidean distance using dates

Comment: @onyambu is correct. you should transform your dates to a distance column/matrix.  also be aware that the scaling that you printed were not assigned to the data (but if everything is measured in the same scale anyway, it is not necessary).